# c# running multiple process.Start() asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, process.start

I have a folder containing multiple PCL files which need converting to PDF. I am able to achieve this using a third party exe. To speed this up I am trying to run multiple Tasks(), each which starts a new System.Diagnostics.Process using the exe;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = $@".\WinPCLtoPDF\WinPCLtoPDF.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"{StepParameters["StagingFileName"]} {StepParameters["StagingFileName"]}.pdf batch";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

The tasks are added to a `List<Task>` and each is awaited before the program exits.

```
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
            {
                tasks.Add(ProcessDocumentTaskAsync(batchType, fileInfo, deleteOriginalFile));

                while (tasks.Count < files.Count() && tasks.Where(x => !x.IsCompleted).Count() > concurrentTasks)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
            }
```

The Tasks are created using a method like this.

```
        private async static Task ProcessDocumentTaskAsync(BatchType batchType, FileInfo fileInfo, bool deleteOriginalFile)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {   
                ProcessParameters processParameters = ProcessParams();/////get process params            
                DocumentProcessor documentProcessor = GetDocumentProcessor(batchType, processParameters);
                using (documentProcessor)
                {
                    documentProcessor.ProcessDocument();
                }
            });
        }
```

This pattern works for other tasks and you can see from a log file that jobs are being performed asynchronously. However, with this WinPCLtoPDF.exe, it appears to only process one file at a time, yet the task manager shows there are multiple processes running. Process 1 & 2 for example will wait, while 3 starts and finishes and is replaced by 4, 5 etc, until finally the whole folder is process and 1 then 2 complete.

Can I find out why 1 & 2 are appear to be being blocked and do not complete quickly, allowing other tasks to start?

Comment: If you could include how are the Tasks created that would be helpful.

Comment: @gpro I've added some code for creating a task. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to use something like this to avoid tying up a thread/task: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/f78b5cb354c259fa1242ad4c1141ad23

Comment: Also, please don't try to invent your own scheduling mechanism, use the built-in stuff, such as `Parallel.ForEach` or `ActionBlock<T>`. These will allow you to control the concurrency.

Comment: It may be that this helpful exe has certain resources that must be used exclusively which limits how many copies can run simultaneously. What happens if you try to launch multiple copies using e.g. a batch file?

Comment: If you want to await a list of `Task`s, use `Task.WhenAll()`. Do not use this kind of while loop. And if you for some reason can't await the `Task` returned by `Task.WhenAll()` use `Task.WaitAll()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, I think you're right the winplc exe is using other resources so can only run one process at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably (as mentioned in a comment) to use `Parallel.ForEach`. In your case it would look something like:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, fileInfo =>
        {
            ProcessParameters processParameters = ProcessParams();/////get process params            
            DocumentProcessor documentProcessor = GetDocumentProcessor(batchType, processParameters);
            using (documentProcessor)
            {
                documentProcessor.ProcessDocument();
            }
        });
```

---

Note on your trying:

The reason it is not running all the Tasks at once is probably because you are awaiting the Task completion in your `ProcessDocumentTaskAsync` function.

Comment: this works perfectly and improves my code but unfortunately the reliance on third party exe means it can actually only run one process per machine. I've used this pattern instead.